# cakephp pagination next and previous not showing

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3

I am using cakephp 1.3 and i am receiving strange problem with pagination.I have imnplemented pagination for I have working pagination code in more than one controller .But my rest of the controller not showing next and previous button and numbers for pagination is working fine
I am using this code in my view

```
<?php 
   if(!empty($zipcodes)){   
        echo "<div class='pagination'>";
        echo @$this->Paginator->prev('« Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); 
        echo @$this->Paginator->numbers();
        echo @$this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); 
        echo '<div style="float:right;padding:5px;color:#000">'.$this->Paginator->counter().'</div>';
        echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

And in my controller i have used pagination controller as i am paginating custom query results .I included pagination code in app_model.php.
My ontroller code is

```
var $paginate = array(
                         'Zipcode' => array('limit' => 5,
                                        'order' => array('id' => 'desc'),                                        


                    )
                    );
```

my query and operation

```
        $tsql = " SELECT Zipcode.* ".
                    " FROM zipcodes AS Zipcode ".
                    " WHERE  Zipcode.region_id=0 ";
               $conditions = array(
                                'tsql'=>$tsql,
                            );
                $tmp =  $this->paginate('Zipcode',$conditions); 
                $this->set('zipcodes', $tmp);
```

can any one point out me what i am doing wrong.??And why pagination is working for only some controller .??? THanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, change your paginate in the top of the controller. Remove Zipcode from it. It should just be:

```
var $paginate = array(
   'limit' => 5,
   'order' => array('Zipcode.id' => 'desc'),                                        
);
```

Second, I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with $tsql, but as far as I know, you cannot pass a SELECT statement as a condition. You need to write ORM specific conditions like this:

```
$this->paginate = array(
  'conditions' => array('Zipcode.region_id' => 0),
);
```

Then to set zipcodes you can do this:

```
$this->set('zipcodes', $this->paginate('Zipcode'));
```

or this

```
$data = $this->paginate('Zipcode');
$this->set(compact('data'));
```

As a side note, `echo @$this->Paginator->prev` should be  `echo $this->Paginator->prev` and all the @ should be removed from those lines. That is poor coding practice. I'm not certain if you have the ignore in there for a reason, but it's bad.

Comment: no, i have been using above method all over in my community site..and that works fine...but some of the controllers making problem...and about the @..i have used it for escaping if that value is empty..thnx for your effort brither ...hope i can go through it again with your suggestions also..

Comment: Using `$tsql` is not correct unless you have some custom method to handle it somewhere else. I have tried to produce this and I get an error. It is setting a condition on the query to look for the `tsql` column in the Zipcode table. If you are messing with the customizing the CakePHP ORM, nobody will be able to answer this question for you. You really should use CakePHP the proper way it is intended or hand spin your code. But the way you are writing it in your post is not correct.

Comment: i have sent you mail in detail..to this mail:cdburgess+blogchuck@gmail.com

Comment: Your email will not change my answer. If you write the code incorrectly and insist it is correct, there is nothing anyone will be able to do to help you. Sorry.